# Anti-Phishing System (a more effective method)

Tags: php, database, security

I'm contacting you all today to request if anyone knows a more "effective" way for creating a custom Anti-Phishing system that can recognize a logged in IP for more than 10 times and consider it a "trusted" source, whereas a new IP (accessed at least 5 times or less) is "Blacklisted" and blocks an account.

This is my Code:

```
    <?php
     $sql="select * from user_table where netuser_id = $_SESSION[netuser_id]";
     $res=mysql_query($sql);
     $data_set=mysql_fetch_array($res);
     if($data_set["current_record"]!=$data_set["last_record"])
     {
?>
<!-- Phishing Announcement -->
You've been phished! D: Please change your account password.
<!-- Phishing Announcement -->
<?php
     }
?>
```

This code is somewhat effective, however my initial thought was to make something like:

```
<?php

$sql="select count(*) as a from current_ips where netuser_id = ".$_SESSION["netuser_id"]." and current_ips = $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR];";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$phished=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($phished==0)
        {
?>
<!-- Phishing Announcement -->
You've been phished! D: Please change your account password.
<!-- Phishing Announcement -->
<?php
        }
        else
        {
?>
<?php
        }
?>
```

However this code isn't as effective, considering that i would like the code to initiate itself only if it's been accessed by an unrecognized IP about 3 times. And disable itself if a recognized ip has been accessed over 5-10 congruent times.

Example:

My IP has accessed my account a total of 230/270 times.
My cousin's IP accessed my account 20 times.
My friend accessed my account 10 times.
And so has my sister.

Therefore it's categorized as a "trusted" source, since the IP is a static one and each time i access the site, it works for me! :)

BUT Let's say i access my account via an unrecognized IP (My dad's house), then i'd like the phishing system to enable itself and prevent me from accessing my account until i changed my password.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You seem to have a different definition of the term "phishing" than I do.

Comment: There are many problems with this type of IP-based system.  One example... some ISP's like AOL use a single IP address (belonging to a proxy server) for tens of thousands of individual users.  Seeing an "unrecognized" IP address is certainly grounds for additional security (e.g. password + answer to secret question), but the scheme you have described is flawed.

Comment: @Cubic - i know, haha. It's actually a totally different definition, it's more of a "hacking alert" system, when i come to think of it.

Comment: @EricJ. - I have no problem with that, however members do report hacking attempts to their accounts. For a fact, the website is secure, i've coded it and got some experts to help out too, but this hacking alert/phishing system is a brilliant thing i don't mind implementing to our services.

Comment: `For a fact, the website is secure,` famous last words. @Blahwhore I have doubts that it is secure since you are still using `mysql_*()` functions. O_o

Comment: @crypticツ omg haha you're right, but it was an example idea. It's not perfect i'll admit, my first one is somewhat effective. But i believe the second one would be slightly better if i added something like: phishing.class.php and installed the sql code there, and bring up the info in a slightly better way. [>.> Okay fine, i'm having issues with the mail server, so to prevent problems i attempted to use the custom phishing thing.]

Comment: First off: stop using the `mysql_` functions...

Comment: @ColeJohnson - i just tried using mysqli_query and i was presented with my page being blank. Is there a specific module i must enable from WHMS?

Answer (score 2):

many different platforms (Google, Facebook, and several major banks) use a 2-factor authentication system using SMS authentication, tho you could very easily employ [Google's 2-auth](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180744&rd=1) mobile app for your [own website](https://code.google.com/p/ga4php/).

In any case, once a user is authenticated using 2FA, you could save a cookie that contains a secret you also save in your database, which will ensure this is a recognizable computer. This cookie should expire in 30 days or so.

This way, you could use extra security measures (like security questions, etc.) when a user is coming from an 'untrusted computer' and once authenticated, save that cookie that will save the user from those measures the next time they come in.

This approach better than relying on IP, which by now are hardly a reliable method of identification.

Comment: dude you're a genius haha, i love cnet by the way. :)
But to respond to your question, i will be looking into this. I didn't even know google's 2-auth method could be used on sites other than those google owns. Cool!